# Get Identify specification of Insert Query ado.net

Tags: c#

I am inserting records in table with inline query.I have to get Identity generated by Insert statement by using Output Parameter, this is how I am doing

```
//Com.CommandText contains Insert Statment
     OleDbParameter IDParameter = new OleDbParameter("@ID", OleDbType.Integer);
                    IDParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    Com.Parameters.Add(IDParameter);
Com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

After executing when I am checking the output parameter value,its appearing 0, althought record is inserting properly
this is how I am checking

```
Com.Parameters[0].Value
```

I also tried this

```
Com.Parameters["@ID"].Value
```

But output parameter value is always 0
I also tried using Select Scope_Identity() inside Insert statment but no luck,
I have also triend ExecuteScalar() but still same issue

Comment: Show us the value of `Com.CommandText`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your insert query must end with

```
SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)
```

Then ExecuteScaler() will return the identity.

```
int ID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: The user mentioned about using ExecuteScaler.

Comment: I feel this is better way to do it and standard practice.